# How to change focus of the items present in the drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I've an app where I've used Drawer layout. eg :

[image]

Here when I click on Gallery then a new Activity gets open. Now when I close that Activity then also the focus is present on the Gallery item, I want to change the focus from the Gallery item to some other item in the drawer options. How can I do that?

I use the following code to display the item list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Import" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Tools" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

So I don't have any clue to change back the focus to the Import item. Please help

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html Check the `selectItem` method in **Handle Navigation Click Events** section. It explains how to set selection

Comment: @Shubhank are you talking about `mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);` this method?

Comment: Yes, you should use that to focus any other position item

Answer (score 1):

Below code make your drawer item unchecked like make it as it was, if you want you can add another to make other item checked

for more details - [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer)

```
findNavController().addOnDestinationChangedListener{_,destination,_ ->
        if (destination.id ==R.id.storageFolderFragment){
            navView.menu.findItem(R.id.storageFolderFragment).isCheckable = false
        }
        if (destination.id ==R.id.categoryDownloadFragment){
            navView.menu.findItem(R.id.categoryDownloadFragment).isCheckable = false
        }
    }
```

Comment: or you can also do it on menu item , isCheckable = true in <item> on your menu

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time but I want to show what worked for me. In case it serves to someone.

First remember to have the `navController` instantiated

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

Then catch the destination change event and use the `setCheckedItem` method of your navigationView like so:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->

        when(destination.id){
            R.id.fragHome -> binding.navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home)
            R.id.fragSettings -> binding.navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_settings)
            R.id.fragAbout -> binding.navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_about)
        }

    }
```

I hope I have been helpful